# Output is printed after each test case instead of altogether at the end

Tags: c++, mergesort

So I was writing code for Merge Sort for a problem to be submitted but instead of the output being printed altogether after all test cases are inputted,it is being printed after each test case which is causing my submission to be wrong.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge(int *a,int start,int mid,int end){
    int temp[end-start+1];
    int i=start,j=mid+1,k=0;
    while(i<=mid&&j<=end){
        if(a[i]<a[j]){
            temp[k++]=a[i++];
        }else{
            temp[k++]=a[j++];
        }
    }
    while(i<=mid){
        temp[k++]=a[i++];
    }
    while(j<=end){
        temp[k++]=a[j++];
    }
    for(int i=start,j=0;i<=end;i++,j++){
        a[i]=temp[j];
    }
    return;
}

void merge_sort(int *a,int start,int end){
    if(start<end){
        int mid=(start+end)/2;
        merge_sort(a,start,mid);
        merge_sort(a,mid+1,end);
        merge(a,start,mid,end);
    }
    return;
}

void mergeSort(int input[], int size){
    merge_sort(input,0,size-1);
}



int main(){
    int t;
    int length;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        cin >> length;
        int* input = new int[length];
        for(int i=0; i < length; i++){
            cin >> input[i];
        }
        mergeSort(input, length);
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            cout << input[i] << " ";
        } 
        cout << endl;
        
    }
}
```

Actual Result :

```
2
5
1 5 6 3 4
1 3 4 5 6 
6
1 6 7 2 5 8
1 2 5 6 7 8
```

Expected Result :

```
2
5
1 5 6 3 4
6
1 6 7 2 5 8
1 3 4 5 6
1 2 5 6 7 8
```

What is wrong with my code in main() while taking test cases?

Comment: Your code is explicitly reading some inputs, sorting them, outputting them, then reading some more inputs ......    If you need to print the results after ALL the inputs have been read, then you need to store all inputs (say, in some form of standard container, such as a set of vectors) until all have been read,  then sort each lot of inputs, then output the required results.

Comment: Why would the test makers insist on all output coming after all input? This makes no sense, and I have never seen this requirement before. It is a needless complication imposed on the person being tested. Maybe the ordering is not the problem, but something else...

Comment: @Peter Can you provide some articles where can I understand how to do this? Unfortunately I am not familiarized with the concept of vectors.

Comment: Are you sure it's not failing on speed, due to the VLA memory allocation?

Comment: When I was new to coding contests, I used to think the same. I can bet the problem is something else. Try some custom inputs, edge cases you can think of and verify.